# How can I translate Romaji text to English?

Tags: translation, rōmaji

I have a block of Japanese-language text that has been transliterated to Romaji that I would like to translate to English.  They are [lyrics to a song](http://www.nautiljon.com/paroles/abe+mao/yada.html).

I have very little experience with the Japanese language.

I am looking for some pointers on how I can achieve this.

Comment: As in, Japanese-language text that's been transliterated to Romaji? What are you struggling with in particular? Can you give some examples? Do you speak Japanese? What level? I hope someone will prove me wrong, but right now your question is probably too vague to get any helpful answers.

Comment: I hope my edits help.

Comment: You could use a dictionary and translate each word individually, then translate groups of words or whole sentences based on the translation of each word. But if you're just after a translation of the lyrics so that you know what's being said, there might be a fan-translation already. Have you tried a websearch for the title of the song with "English Translation" after it? Have you checked on YouTube? Most translations of songs end up on YouTube as fan-made "karaoke" videos (music video/still images, with kana/kanji and English translation on screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no clue as to what kind of answer to your question is possible, and usually, this kind of question is closed, but for the particular lyrics, here is my translation (the romaji transcription has a few mistakes, so it is partly based on my guess):

> I like you, but I cannot like the girl that you like. I cannot. Rather, I hate her.
>
> I peeked to see you while being careful that no one notices and while encouraging myself. What I saw was you gazing at her while being careful that no one notices. I hate it. I could tell your voice from a distant place, but what I heard was her name sung by your lips.
>
> Why is it her? Why is it not me? My God, why did you not let me come to know him earlier?
>
> I like you, but I cannot like the girl that you like. I cannot. Rather, I hate her.
>
> If I were to know your body, my heart would beat stronger and get warmer. But what can ring your mind is the breath spilled out from her.
>
> Why is it her? I am better. My God, please let him awake from his dream as soon as possible.
>
> I would like to love whatever you love, but regarding her, it is just impossible. I cannot like her. Because ...
>
> I do not like it that your retina, your hollow voice, your large hands, and your warm back, all belong to her. I cannot tolerate it by now. I have been watching all but you.
>
> I like you, but (I cannot like her. I cannot like her.) I would like to behave, but ... (what I do not like is what do not like) I cannot.
>
> I like you, but I cannot like the girl that you like. I cannot. Rather, I hate her.